# FFMPEG blinking overlay

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a pretty complex (for me) video manipulation to complete:

- get a source video
- crop it
- flip it
- overlay with an image: 3s OFF, 80s ON

I've managed to complete first steps:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i source.flv -vf "movie=overlay.jpg [logo]; 
           [in] crop=854:430:0:50 [crop]; [crop] hflip [flipped]; 
           [flipped][logo] overlay=0:0 [out]" 
           -c:v h264 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

But I really don't know where to start to make the overlay appear and disappear multiple times during the video...

I took a look at [overlay filter manual](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) and saw this sample
`overlay=x='if(gte(t,2), -w+(t-2)*20, NAN)':y=0`
Maybe I could use a similar formula for my purposes: if remainder(t/83) <=2 then NAN, otherwise 0:0... but how can I compute remainder? In C# I can use t%83, but what about ffmpeg?
Is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

I finally found a solution playing with the sample and reading [Expression Evaluation page](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation):

```
ffmpeg.exe -i source.flv -vf "movie=overlay.jpg [logo]; 
           [in] crop=854:430:0:50 [crop]; 
           [crop] hflip [flipped]; 
           [flipped][logo] overlay=x='if(lt(mod(t,83),3),NAN,0)':y=0 [out]" 
           -c:v h264 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

The idea is to find the remainder of t/83: if it's less than 3 then overlay mustn't be shown, otherwise yes.
Hope it helps...

Comment: [Timeline editing](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) may be useful. You can dump the `movie` multimedia source filter and shorten the command somewhat: `ffmpeg -i source.flv -i overlay.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]crop,hflip[cf];[cf][1:v]overlay...`